# Getting error in configuration of hibernate , mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

i am new to hibernate .
and I am getting error like 
hibernate.properties not found and Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am using MySqlWorkbench version 5.7.19
and hibernate version 5.2.6.Final
jdk 1.8 with eclipse oxygen

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">gary@1234</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
```

and here is pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
```

and here is my code

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Alien alien = new Alien();
    alien.setAid(101);
    alien.setAname("pawan");
    alien.setColor("purple");
    Configuration con = new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(alien);
    tx.commit();
}}
```

and this is pojo class

```
public class Alien {

@Id
private int aid;
private String aname;
private String color;

public int getAid() {
    return aid;
}

public void setAid(int aid) {
    this.aid = aid;
}

public String getAname() {
    return aname;
}

public void setAname(String aname) {
    this.aname = aname;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your database user is 'root' and your password is 'gary@1234'?

Comment: yes other application without hibernate is working fine on same

Comment: Where did you place your hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: i created it by using hibernate plugin and in the src/main/java

Comment: Can you show the actual error message?

Comment: Aug 16, 2017 3:10:23 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.6.Final}
Aug 16, 2017 3:10:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Aug 16, 2017 org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Aug 16, 2017 3:10:25 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann the error log is quite big so i add as much as it accomodate

Comment: Hey @TobiasGeiselmann i got the solution and it working for me.

Comment: yes @AMallal You are right .I did it also so now my problem is solved . thanks for your valuable response

Comment: If it is right, please show it as correct answer in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to all for giving your precious time .
i got the solution by just makin changes as

```
Configuration con = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Alien.class);
```

Actually it was not getting the properties of hibernate.cfg.xml and class as well

Answer (score 0):

You shold add `@Entity` to `Alien`, as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Alien {

//...

}
```

Comment: That is OK. You can test my solution. If you have many class, adding `@Entity` to entity class is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Using password: YES, means, the password you have entered to connect to the database is not correct.